# pdfjs -dist render text with spaces between the some of the letters

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

using pdfjs- dist library render page not currently.
images are render ok but letters are render with space between some of the letters withut a reason. for example-
'h ello w orl d'
[image]
version of pdfjs-dist 3.4.120

the code:

```
import React, {createRef, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { SERVICE_URL, METHODS } from '../../utils/Dec.js';

import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';

import './MobileDocView.css';

import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack';

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'build/pdf.worker.bundle.js'
// import {pdfjsWorker} from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry.js';

 

 const MobileDocView = () => {    

 const [src, setSrc] = useState('https://dorms.huji.ac.il/media/1303/dorms-information-brochure.pdf?&~nfopt(fileDistorted=16589236245947614)');

  const canvasRef = useRef([]);

  const pdf = useRef(1);

  const currentPage = useRef(1);

  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState();

 

  function handlePages(page)

  {

    const canvas = canvasRef.current[currentPage.current - 1];

      let ctx = canvas.current.getContext("2d");

      let dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

      let bsr =

        ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||

        ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||

        ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||

        ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||

        ctx.backingStorePixelRatio ||

        1;

      let ratio = dpr / bsr;

      let viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });

      canvas.current.width = viewport.width * ratio;

      canvas.current.height = viewport.height * ratio;

      canvas.current.style.width = viewport.width + "px";

      canvas.current.style.height = viewport.height + "px";

      // ctx.font = '24px Sans'

      ctx.setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);

      let renderContext = {

        canvasContext: ctx,

        viewport: viewport,

      };

      page.render(renderContext);

 
      currentPage.current = currentPage.current + 1

      if ( pdf.current !== null && currentPage.current <= numPages )

      {

          pdf.current.getPage( currentPage.current ).then( handlePages );

      }

  }

  async function getDoc() { 

    try { 

      const response = await fetch(src, { credentials: 'include' });

      const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

      const bufferAsTypedArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument({ data: bufferAsTypedArray });

      pdf.current = await loadingTask.promise; 

      canvasRef.current = (Array(pdf.current.numPages).fill().map((_, i) => createRef()))

      setNumPages( pdf.current.numPages);

      pdf.current.getPage(1).then(handlePages);

    } catch (error) {

      console.error('error:',error);

    }

  }


  useEffect(() => {

     getDoc();

  }, [])

 

  return(

    <div className='pdf-viewer'>

     {numPages ? canvasRef.current.map((item, i) => (<canvas key={i} ref= {canvasRef.current[i]} style={{ height: '100vh'}} />))

     :  <span><CircularProgress />טוען קובץ</span>}

</div>  ) 

}

 

export default MobileDocView;
```

I checked some version of this library. also tr some example of render the page but all without success.
I'll be grateful for any solution